# Image appear black downloaded from server

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I am using glide to load image from Sd Card which is downloaded from server and then write into Sdcard.

Some time Image appear half black and some time image appear fully black. Like given image.

Unable to get the reason.
Images are loading in recycle list items.
[image]

One thing I want to mention that image after downloading, appear correctly in the sdcard, problem is while reading from sdcard to image view.

Comment: I think image might have not downloaded properly. But one thing I'm not getting why are you storing image into SD card instead of directly fetching it from server & showing into the app?

Comment: for offine usage of the application

Comment: One thing i want to mention that image after downloading  , appear correctly in the sdcard ,problem is while reading from sdcard to image view.

Comment: Have you tried loading image using Picasso?

Comment: Same Issue with some images.

Comment: Are you compressing your images? And also which format are you using?

Comment: No not compressing the images after downloading.@